# How to read Parquet file using Spark Core API?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

How to read Parquet file using Spark Core API?

I know using Spark SQL has some methods to read parquet file. But we cannot use Spark SQL for our projects.

Do we have to use `newAPIHadoopFile` method on `JavaSparkContext` to do this?

I am using Java to implement Spark Job.

Comment: Can you use the sqlContext? `val file = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:///somefile.parquet").rdd`  How about HiveContext? `val file = hc.load("somefile.parquet")` If not, `newAPIHadoopFile` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").appName("Application").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().parquet(filename);
```